# Getting error while trying to view Heroku app

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm new to using Rails as well as Heroku and have been trying to push an app that works just fine locally. I am able to push it to heroku (seemingly), but when I try to view it, I get

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
```

I from digging through similar SO post, I think it has something to do with the database the app is using within heroku but so far using `heroku run rake db:reset` and then `heroku run rake db:migrate` has returned the exact same error. I'm sure I have done something terribly misguided here but I am hoping someone can help me figure it out. Here's what I get with `heroku logs`:

```
2017-01-26T05:24:34.232181+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-01-26T05:24:34.232138 #4]  INFO -- : [7baf7e95-1518-4773-9f3c-39aef34651f2] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
2017-01-26T05:24:34.233452+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-01-26T05:24:34.233406 #4] FATAL -- : [7baf7e95-1518-4773-9f3c-39aef34651f2]   
2017-01-26T05:24:34.233498+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-01-26T05:24:34.233455 #4] FATAL -- : [7baf7e95-1518-4773-9f3c-39aef34651f2] ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
2017-01-26T05:24:34.233500+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LI...
2017-01-26T05:24:34.233501+00:00 app[web.1]:                                ^
2017-01-26T05:24:34.233501+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT $1):
2017-01-26T05:24:34.233649+00:00 app[web.1]: [7baf7e95-1518-4773-9f3c-39aef34651f2]     21:       <div class="container">
2017-01-26T05:24:34.233648+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-01-26T05:24:34.233606 #4] FATAL -- : [7baf7e95-1518-4773-9f3c-39aef34651f2]     20:     <div class="header">
2017-01-26T05:24:34.233650+00:00 app[web.1]: [7baf7e95-1518-4773-9f3c-39aef34651f2]     22:         <a href="../messages"><h1 class="logo">MessagesApp</h1> <img class="logo-img" src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/titanfall/images/3/3a/Icon_Chat.png/revision/latest?cb=20140504182858"></a>
2017-01-26T05:24:34.233650+00:00 app[web.1]: [7baf7e95-1518-4773-9f3c-39aef34651f2]     23:           <% if logged_in? %>
2017-01-26T05:24:34.233651+00:00 app[web.1]: [7baf7e95-1518-4773-9f3c-39aef34651f2]     24:             <%= link_to "Log out".html_safe, logout_path, method: "delete", class: "login-btn btn btn-default navbar-btn" %>
2017-01-26T05:24:34.233652+00:00 app[web.1]: [7baf7e95-1518-4773-9f3c-39aef34651f2]     25:           <% else %>
2017-01-26T05:24:34.233652+00:00 app[web.1]: [7baf7e95-1518-4773-9f3c-39aef34651f2]     26:             <%= link_to "Log in".html_safe, login_path, class: "login-btn btn btn-default navbar-btn" %>
2017-01-26T05:24:34.233692+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-01-26T05:24:34.233648 #4] FATAL -- : [7baf7e95-1518-4773-9f3c-39aef34651f2]   
2017-01-26T05:24:34.233718+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-01-26T05:24:34.233685 #4] FATAL -- : [7baf7e95-1518-4773-9f3c-39aef34651f2] app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:7:in `current_user'
2017-01-26T05:24:34.233718+00:00 app[web.1]: [7baf7e95-1518-4773-9f3c-39aef34651f2] app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:11:in `logged_in?'
2017-01-26T05:24:34.233719+00:00 app[web.1]: [7baf7e95-1518-4773-9f3c-39aef34651f2] app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:23:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1527317900822670125_70088753231660'
2017-01-26T05:24:34.240424+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=nameless-bayou-71899.herokuapp.com request_id=7baf7e95-1518-4773-9f3c-39aef34651f2 fwd="207.67.119.130" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=12ms status=500 bytes=1733
```

here is what I believe is relevant code:

```
<% @messages.each do |message| %>
    <div class="message <%= 'right' if logged_in? && message.user_id==current_user.id %>">

      <% if message.user_id==current_user.id %>
        <%= '<p class="user_name text-right">Me</p>'.html_safe %>
      <% else %>
        <p class="user_name"><%= message.user.name %></p>
      <% end %>

    <p class="content"><%= message.content %></p>
    <p class="time <%= 'right' if message.user_id==current_user.id %>"><%= time_ago_in_words(message.created_at) %><br>
      <% if message.user_id==current_user.id %>
        <%= link_to 'Delete', message_path(message),
            class: "delete-link",
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></p>
      <% end %>
    </div>
      <% end %>
```

Comment: try `heroku pg:reset DATABASE; heroku run rake db:migrate` - this will totally reset the db

Comment: thanks, I tried that just now and got this: `StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
: CREATE TABLE "messages" ("id" serial primary key, "content" text, "users_id" integer, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_e3b11c0cbb"
FOREIGN KEY ("users_id")
  REFERENCES "users" ("id")
)`

Comment: Your migrations are in the wrong order. Reset your db on your local and make it work there first.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried resetting locally as well as within heroku before posting this. already works fine local, always has. its production thru heroku that is giving me headaches

Comment: Probably you have wrong `create_messages` migration file. Message should have `user_id` field, not `user*s*_id`, so foreign key should not be like this `FOREIGN KEY ("users_id")`. Try to fix it and run migration again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to divide migration for messages model to two separate migrations. First migration creates model. second migration adds reference relation